# Unable to find Google Shopping API on Google Cloud Console

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform

Example [image]Im trying to integrate the Google Shopping API into my application to display product information from different stores. However, I'm having trouble locating the API on the Google Cloud Console. I've followed the documentation and searched through the available APIs, but I can't seem to find the Google Shopping API.

I have already created a project on the Google Cloud Console, and I have enabled several other APIs successfully. But when I search for "Google Shopping API" in the API Library, it doesn't appear in the results.

Am I missing something? Is the Google Shopping API available on the Google Cloud Console, or is it deprecated? If it's available, how can I enable it for my project? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this [link](https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/guides/quickstart) help?